# How to make <option>s of <select> show or hide using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want to make the options of < select > show or hide by program(JS),is it possible?

It is just like the interesting tags in the front page of StackOverFlow, when you type in some words, the drop list will expand and give you suggestions.

ps.I know StackOverFlow didn't use select in this case, anyway just take it as an example.

Comment: use an input text box, ajax as the user types in say 2 characters at least, then output the results as a list (ul) formatted like a dropdown menu using CSS.

Comment: yeah,thanks,it is also what I thought was the best solution,I also have noticed that StackOverFlow use this method instead of < select > in the case which I mentioned above.

Comment: See this to hide/show options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21199399/32429

Answer (score 1):

You add or remove items from the `options` collection of the `select`.

Here is an example that removes one item and adds another:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
  // get a reference to the element
  var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
  // remove an option
  sel.options[2] = null;
  // create a new option and add to the select
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = '5';
  opt.text = 'five';
  sel.options.add(opt);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<form>

<select id="sel">
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems that you didn't get my point,anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @DiveInto: In that case I still don't. What point are you talking about, and what is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCatListdef(sel)
{
    var index = ajax.length;
    ajax[index] = new sack();
     ajax[index].requestFile = 'data.php?cat_code='+sel;
     ajax[index].onCompletion = function(){ createCities(index) };  
    ajax[index].runAJAX();    
}
```

Comment: How does this answer help? What is `ajax`? What is `sack`?