# Jquery hide/show optgroup base on main selector

Tags: jquery, show-hide, multiple-select, optgroup

Please refer to this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wnFXX/7/) , is a multiple select box to select sub-activity base on what is picked in main-activity, its working pretty well now.

Based on change request, I want to make the action to **show only** the optgroup in sub-activity when it being select, means when you select `main-activity option 1 and 2`, `sub-activity` are show optgroup for `1 and 2`, the rest are hide and not visible, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to get not selected options and `hide()` them in subactivity. and not forget to show selected ones.

```
 //get not selected ones
 var arr1 = $('#filterActivity option:not(:selected)');

  //iterate and hide 
  $("#filterSubActivity").children("optgroup[label='" + arr1[j].value + "']").hide();
```

here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/q62PK/

Comment: i have firefox right now i will try again in chrome and let you know

Comment: it seems like `hide()` option does not work in Chrome and IE, just Firefox implemented it for `option`.

Comment: you might be able to get it working with using `append` and `remove` functions. i have tried it but it kind of gets messy. if you spend some time you can do it i think though

Comment: refer to this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699410/hiding-options-of-a-select-with-jquery

Comment: if you get it to work please add it to your question and let me know i would like to see

Comment: What I did instead was create a JSON object where I store all my options for the select with their respective option group. I reload the group the user selects from the object.  It re-draws all the options each time you toggle the filter so probably not the best approach for long lists of items but works like a charm for my needs.

Comment: This works in Chrome and FF but not in IE 11 (it does work in Edge)