# Filter Category Select Drop down based on Another drop down option

Tags: jquery

I want to filter the list of options based on the selection of another drop down.

Please see the jquery code below; i am sure there is a tiny bit that i am missing that's why it is not working.

```
if($('#selectionone').is(':selected')){
    $('option').filter('.edibles');   

}
if($('selectiontwo').is(':selected')){
  $('option').filter('.vegfats');
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/joey_ma/Wa4ZF/6/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my approach of adding/removing options based on the options selected and this will work in most of browsers.

I have modified the html by adding class to first select options like

```
<option class="edibles" value="Edible Oils" id="selectionone">Edible Oils</option>
<option class="vegfats" value="Vegetable Cooking Fats" id="selectiontwo">Vegetable Cooking Fats</option>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var allOptions = $('#selectprod option')
    $('#selectcat').change(function () {
        $('#selectprod option').remove(); //remove all options
        var classN = $('#selectcat option:selected').prop('class'); //get the 
        var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN); //selected option's classname
        $.each(opts, function (i, j) {
            $(j).appendTo('#selectprod'); //append those options back
        });
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa4ZF/9/)

Comment: Thanks Praveen for this man, it works just the way i wanted it to. I appreciate it mate, cheers!

Comment: @JoeyNg'ethe I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: I have copied the code from JSFiddle and pasted it in html file, but that is not working as it is on JSFiddle itself...Any Help !

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple approach to the issue, which should be rather solid:

```
<select class="masterSelect">
    <option value="0">Fiat</option>
    <option value="1">Opel</option>
    <option value="2">Porsche</option>
</select>

<div class="hiddenOptions">
    <select>
        <option value="1">Punto</option>
        <option value="2">Mani</option>
        <option value="3">Pierri 203</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="4">Elysis</option>
        <option value="5">201</option>
        <option value="6">Mido</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="7">911</option>
        <option value="8">Macho</option>
        <option value="9">Vanguard</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hiddenOptions > select
{
   display: none;
}

.hiddenOptions > select.active
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.masterSelect').on('change', function() {
    $('.hiddenOptions select').removeClass("active");
    $('.hiddenOptions select').eq($(this).val()).addClass("active");

    showValue();
});

$('.hiddenOptions select').on('change', function() {
    showValue();
});

$('.masterSelect').trigger('change'); //set initial value on load

function showValue()
{
    console.log($('.hiddenOptions select.active').val());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g5h2k6t4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectcat').change(function () {
        $('#selectprod option').show();
        if ($('option:selected', this).attr('id') == 'selectionone') {
            $('#selectprod option.edibles').hide();
        }
        if ($('option:selected', this).attr('id') == 'selectiontwo') {
            $('#selectprod option.vegfats').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kwJwM/)**

As this may not work in older versions of IE, you can replace `$('#selectprod option').show();` with `$('#selectprod option').prop('disabled',false);` and `$('#selectprod option.vegfats').hide();` with `$('#selectprod option.vegfats').prop('disabled',true);`

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. Anyway, `show` and `hide` won't work on Chrome, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699410/hiding-options-of-a-select-with-jquery

Comment: @t0mppa - I do most of my work in Chrome and it works fine there.

Comment: @j08691 it will work in chrome and FF but fails in IE.  A better approach is to add `disabled` attribute to those options better for IE.  Best approach would be removing and adding options dynamcially.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan - true, answer updated with disabled property.

Comment: @j08691: Certainly doesn't work on my Chromium, but maybe I just have an old version then. EDIT: Doesn't work even after update with *Version 30.0.1589.0 (215899)*

Answer (score -2):

Include these two links along with the code given by **Praveen**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```