# How to apply show/hide condition in Jquery while using Select option?

Tags: jquery

I have two select fields. In first field I have some data. I want to hide option of second field by click of first field option.

**First Field**

```
<select id="edit-main-field-i-am-field-und" class="form-select required">
<option value="_none">- Select a value -</option>
<option value="sbA">A</option>
<option value="sdB">B</option>
<option value="smC">C</option>
<option value="sbD">D</option>
</select>
```

**Second Field**

```
<select id="edit-main-field-look-for-field-und" class="form-select required">
<option value="_none">- Select a value -</option>
<option value="sbA">A</option>
<option value="sdB">B</option>
<option value="smC">C</option>
<option value="sbD">D</option>
</select>
```

I want If I select A or C from first field then A & C is hide from Second field & If I select  B or D from first field then B & D is hide from second field. I try this through JQuery but problem to hide add condition.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {  
    $("#edit-main-field-i-am-field-und").change(function() {
       if($('option:selected', this).text()=="A" || $('option:selected', this).text()=="C" )
        {alert("12345");}
      else if($('option:selected', this).text()=="B" || $('option:selected', this).text()=="D" )
        {alert("98765");}

    });
});
</script>
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: What's this in your question? _else if($('option:selected', this).text()=="Sugar Daddy" || $('option:selected', this).text()=="Sugar Baby (Male)" )_

Comment: Updated.. by mistake.. May u pls help me to solve this @MelanciaUK

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter Category Select Drop down based on Another drop down option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477406/filter-category-select-drop-down-based-on-another-drop-down-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : by using selected value of `select` box get the text of `option` and `filter()` all options with matched `text()` to `hide()` them.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#edit-main-field-i-am-field-und").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var optionText = $(this).find('option[value='+value+']').text();
    //show all options by default
    $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').show();

       if(optionText=="A" || optionText=="C" )
       {
         alert("12345");
           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).text()=="A" || $(this).text()=="C")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }
      else
       {
           alert("98765");
           $('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und').find('option').filter(function(){
               if($(this).text()=="B" || $(this).text()=="D")
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }).hide();
       }

    });
});
</script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/8/)**

Comment: happy to help you Veera :)

Comment: I try to fetch through Option Value i.e. .value(); in place of .text(); & update sbA in place of A & so on..
but its not working.. @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: use `.val()` instead of `.value()`

Comment: I have found 1 issue.. If first I select A from first field then in second field I have 2 option to select i.e. B or D & If I selected B from second field. And again goto first field & If I select B in first field & without select option second field. Form is submitted with B option in second field. How to solve this issue

Comment: to resolve this issue put `$('#edit-main-field-look-for-field-und option:visible:eq(1)').prop('selected',true);});` after `if/else` block. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/17/). If you want to make `select a value` option by default then use `eq(0)` instead of `eq(1)`, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/18/)

Comment: It's not working.. :( If first I select option from second field i.e. A & after that from first field if I select A & if I submit form without selecting option from Second field it goes to submit @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: are you seeing change in second list when you select option from first list as I showed in http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/17/?

Comment: Ya I see the changes but did u check. First select A from Second field & now you select A from First field. After selecting A from first field if you don't touch the second field & you submit then submit with A from both field.

Comment: I have put alert to show selected value of second list after selecting option from second list and it is showing correctly, see this http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/19/ . can you put alert and check value of second list before submit a form?